# Pagination in RecyclerView

Tags: android, pagination, onscrolllistener

I am trying you apply infinite scroll in my app. I use recyclerViews, loaders(data from API) and onScrollListener.

Now everything works fine. Even when I scroll and the threshold is reached the data is loaded by the loader, data object is created, sent to the updateDataset function in the adapter class and added to the list there. The only thing that is not happening(and ofc only thing that matters) is that the new items are not added to the list.
Following is my update function 
[image: this is the update function inside the adapter, which is called onLoadFinished loader callback]

Please help me fix this, why is notifyItemRangeInserted not working here and adding items to the list

Comment: remove mArticles.clear();

Comment: Thank you. It works